# $f(x)=x\ln x-\frac{k}{x}$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f'\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\not=0$

Tags: analysis, inequality, numerical-methods

> If $f(x)=x\ln x-\frac{k}{x}$. And $x_1$, $x_2$ are two roots of
>   $f(x)=0$. Then $f'\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\not=0$

First, I determine the range of $k$. Because $f=0$ has two roots $\iff$ $x^2\ln x = k$ has two roots. so we have $-\frac{1}{e}<k<0$.and $0<x_1,x_2<1$

---

I think the difficulty is $\ln x$ can't take part in algebra calculation with $x,x^2, \frac{1}{x}$ etc. So I want to use some polynomial approximate $\ln x$.Here is the Taylor expansion of $\ln x$:

$$\ln x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\left(x-1\right)^n}{n},x\in(0,2]$$

I have tried first order approximate, seems can't work out the problem. Maybe this method can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose wlog that $x_1>x_2$, and let $a=\frac{x_1+x_2}2$, $b=\frac{x_1-x_2}2$. You've shown that $k<0$, so
$$
  f^{(3)}(x)=-\frac1{x^2}+\frac{6k}{x^4}<0
$$
for $x>0$. Hence $f'(x)$ is strictly concave down, so
$$
  2f'(a)>f'(a-t)+f'(a+t)
$$
for $t\in(0,a)$. Integrating,
$$
  2bf'(a)>\int_0^bf'(a-t)+f'(a+t)\;dt
    =\int_{a-b}^{a+b}f'(x)\;dx
    =f(x_1)-f(x_2)=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ is both decreasing and greater than 0. Because of this, $$\left|\int_r^x\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}dt\right|=\left|\frac{df}{dx}\right|$$ is greater at $r-a$ than at $r+a$ where $r$ is the root of $df/dx$ and $a$ is any $0<a<r$. Therefore, $f(r-a)>f(r+a)$. Thus, the smaller root of $f(x)$ is closer to $r$ than the larger and thus $r$ does not lie halfway between the roots at $(x_1+x_2)/2$